# Display a specific line in a text file - android/java

Tags: java, android, string, text

I'm trying to build an app which displays fun facts from a text file. To do this I get a random number and then display that specific line number from the file.When I run the app and try and press the button all I get is a blank text field. Here is my code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fun_facts);
    // Declare and assign variables
    final TextView factLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.factTextView);
    Button showFactButton =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.showFactButton);
    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /*
            code here runs when button click is detected by line 29
            code shows new fact
            */
            String fact = "";
            //get a random number to select a fact
            Random randomNumberGenrator = new Random();//construct random object
            int randomNumber = randomNumberGenrator.nextInt(391);
            FileReader fr = null;
            try {
                fr = new FileReader("facts.txt ");//construct filereader and assign file
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();//exception raised
            }
            LineNumberReader getFact = new LineNumberReader(fr);//construct lineNumberReader
            getFact.setLineNumber(randomNumber);//set current line number to random number
            try {
                fact = getFact.readLine();//read current line and assign it to fact
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            factLabel.setText(fact);
            try {
                getFact.close();//close lineReader
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                fr.close();//close fileReader
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    showFactButton.setOnClickListener(listener);
}
```

Comment: `"facts.txt "` contains a space

Answer (score 0):

Do you getting any errors?

check this line, maybe its typo but worth check it and remove that space from path.
OLD:
fr = new FileReader("facts.txt ");
NEW: 
fr = new FileReader("facts.txt");

Comment: Yeah the emulator simply says "FunFacts has stopped". The logcat says that it has suspended all theades. Gradle has nothing

Comment: You given External storage permissions?